# Powershell - Export array to Html

Tags: arrays, powershell, export-to-html

I need a script that fetches the information and generates an HTML document.
I'm looking for a way to make the columns of my report more friendly so I saw that it is possible to change them with [PSCustomObject] but after I go through this process the data. "System.Object[]" appears instead of the information. Can you help me?

```
$proc = Get-Process | select "ProcessName","ID"
$proc = foreach ($Procs in $proc) {
      [PSCustomObject]@{
          'Process Name' = $proc.processname
          'identification' = $proc.id          
      }  
    }
$out = $proc | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Process Name","identification"
$out | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\file.html"
```

[image]

Comment: You're enumerating over `$proc` and your item is `$Procs` yet on each loop iteration you're assigning the entire collection ( `$proc`) to your object's properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me :)

```
$objects=@()

$processes = Get-Process | select "ProcessName","ID"
foreach ($proc in $processes) {
      $objects+=[PSCustomObject]@{
          'Process Name' = $proc.processname
          'identification' = $proc.id          
      }  
}

$out = $objects | ConvertTo-Html
$out | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\file.html"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer was exactly what I needed.